# Digital signature in OSX with smartcard and BC

Tags: java, macos, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm using Java/BC for digitally signing, on OSX, the keystore is initialized using:

```
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore", "Apple");
keystore.load(null, null);
```

And signature generated by:

```
ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider(provider).build(pkey);
SignerInfoGenerator sigInfoGen = sigInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(sigGen, new X509CertificateHolder(x509.getEncoded()));
```

When "Apple" is the **provider**, I get following error:

```
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: no such algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA for provider Apple
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.unitech.crypto.signers.CmsSigner.sign(CmsSigner.java:51)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA for provider Apple
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:101)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:218)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:405)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.ProviderJcaJceHelper.createSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createSignature(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

On the other hand, if the **provider** is "BC" I get:

```
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: Supplied key (null) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.unitech.crypto.signers.CmsSigner.sign(CmsSigner.java:51)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (null) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi.engineInitSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1174)
    at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:527)
    ... 6 more
```

The **pkey** is in a connected smartcard (accessible from keychain), and I can sign with it using PKCS#11 routines, but could be better for me to do it through BC.

Any help/idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  Java can see my smartcard but when I call KeyStore.isKeyEntry(alias) it returns false whereas on Windows it returns true.

Comment: No luck. But PKCS#11 let me do all I need, at least for OSX, even *nix. Same method works on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what I ended up doing too (PKCS11).

Answer (score 2):

Bouncy Castle is a software only provider. It cannot handle hardware keys, so you need to use either the Apple or PKCS#11 provider. The whole idea of secure hardware tokens is that the keys *stay in the device*. BC requires the keys to be *in memory*.

You may want to try other signature generation functions such as `"SHA256withRSA"`. Using SHA-1 to sign messages is considered insecure by now.

Comment: I thought that "keychain"/apple were like "windows-my", may be not.